# Модератор - це упорядник чи впорядник?

Tags: вибір-слова

Під час пошуку українського відповідника до слова "модератор" на сайті [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/moderator) наткнувася на варіант "впорядник", і все б нічого, але такого слова немає в СУМі, однак там є "[упорядник](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/moderator)".

Отож чи можна вживати слово "впорядник" і чи не буде воно суперечити правилам українського словотвору?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У [СУМі в 11 т.](http://sum.in.ua/s/uporjadnyk)  знаходимо слово **впорядник**:

> **УПОРЯ́ДНИК (ВПОРЯ́ДНИК)**, а, чол.
>
> 1. Той, хто організовує, влаштовує що-небудь. Впорядники вистави можуть їх [інсценівки] скорочувати, збільшувати, заміняти іншими (Степан Васильченко, III, 1960, 274).
> 2. Той, хто створює що-небудь (збірник, словник і т. ін.), систематизуючи, складаючи, підбираючи в певному порядку якийсь матеріал.

Також в українській мові є слово [впорядковувати](http://slovopedia.org.ua/41/53394/263143.html). Зрозуміло, що українська мова має закони милозвучності, тому краще вживати **упорядник**.

Comment: Я так розімію, Анатолій (автор запитання) став «жертвою» того, що на сайті [sum.in.ua](http://sum.in.ua) (або якомусь іншому електронному дзеркалі «Словника української мови» в 11 томах) неідеально працює пошук.

Answer (score 2):

Це ж те саме слово... Хай сучасний український правопис і розділяє слова з фонетичним "чергуванням" у-в, та такі слова треба вважати за різні фонетичні здійснення одного слова. Точнісінько як "учора" та "вчора" це одне слово, "упорядник" та "впорядник" також те саме слово. "У-" — по приголосці, чи на початку мовного потоку, "в-" — після голоски. Крім того, яке саме є здійснення, [u-], чи [w~u̯], часто залежить від окремого мовця та того, як він вибирає промовити речення. На приклад, якшо слово "А" кінчається на голоску, а наступне слово, слово "Б", починається на префікс "у-/в-" з приголоскою після, то чи вимове мовець те "у-/в-" як [u], чи [u̯], чи [w] (нескладове) залежатиме від нього. Якшо зробити невеличкий спин (павзу) перед словом "Б", то фонотактично вимова з [u] цілком виправдана, й не вважатиметься помилковою, і також вимова з [w] ([ʍ] — перед глухими приголосками) не вважатиметься помилковою, бо вибір початкового здійснення "у-/в-" в ізолованих словах залежить від говірок. Дехто любе казати (ізольовано, мається на гадці) "все", дехто "усе", й нема тому ради.

Візьмімо "казала" за слово "А", а "вчора" за слово "Б". Тобто:

1. казала + [спин] + вчора —> "в-":

- [u-] — правильно; частіше;
- [w~ʍ-] — правильно; рідше, залежить від говірки;
- [u̯-] — неправильно; потребує безперервного мовного потоку, шоби втворити дифтонг з попередньою голосною "а": /-a͡ў-/ (казал-ау-чора); [ska'zɑla͡u̯'t͡ʃɔɾa]

2. казала + вчора (без спину) —> "в-";

- [u̯-] — правильно;
- [u-] — неправильно; надто сонорний звук;
- [w~ʍ-] — неправльно; недостаньо сонорний звук.

Розділення тям за префіксами "у-", чи "в-", чи штучне нехтування "чергуванням" у-в то є річ перейнята в часи радянщини. Вона для нашої мови штучна. Про це згадує Юрій Шевелів у роботі "Історична фонологія української мови" (з перекладеної книги; розділи 19.4 - 19.5, сторінки 385-386):

> Відступ чергування ***u- : v-: ø*** зумовлений щонайрізноманітнішими причинами. З-поміж них найголовніші є зовнішні щодо фонологічної еволюції української мови як такої. До них може належати, зокрема, зазначена тенденція до "термінологізації" деяких шарів лексики в технологізованому суспільстві, яке радо послуговується термінами з однією фонетичною фіксованою формою. Однак це може бути й просто намагання знайти раціональне застосування наслідкам потужного впливу з боку російської мови, в основному прийманого нормалізаторами літературної мови, а відтак пропаґандованого в офіційному вжитку та освіті:  російська мова не знає чергування ***u: v***. Нарешті, мляве витіснення **[w]** губно-зубним **v** у всіх позиціях, крім кінця слова та поствоакічної перед приголосним, руйнує саму основу чергування ***u- :v-;*** у вигляді ***u-:[w]*** воно може легко зумовлюватися позиційно, тимчасом як за варіанту ***u-:[v]*** артикуляторна відстань між альтернантами суттєво збільшується, а фонетична зумовленість чергування зменшується.

І ше важливо, мовлячи про новотвори, ось:

> У цілому чергування ***u- : v-: ø*** дарма що непродуктивне стосовно нових слів і обмежене стосовно давньої лексики, ще й досі охоплює більшість тих морфем, які за визначенням мали б йому підлягати

> Звуки ***j*** та ***v*** на початку слова перед приголосними модна було б розглядати як алофони ***i*** та ***u*** відповідно, але в сучасній українській мові, внаслідок появи пар слів без чергування на кшталт *впра́ва - упра́ва*, ситуація змінилася

(Даруйте за можливі помилки, довелося самотужки перенабирати з книги).

Answer (score 1):

В сучасному «Словнику української мови» в 20 томах є «впорядник»:

> [**ВПОРЯ́ДНИК**](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=142067&page=537) *див[итись]* **упоря́дник**.

Answer (score 1):

Відповідно до [правил милозвучності](http://p-for.com/book_293_glava_30_%C2%A7_25._Pravila_milozvuchnost%D1%96.html):

> **В українській мові чергуються** як прийменники у, в, так і **префік­си у-, в-** чи початкові звуки кореня.
>
> в) після голосного перед більшістю приголосних, крім в, ф, хв,
> льв, св і под. (див.: п. 1; в): **пізно *в*же**.

Таким чином якщо попереднє слово закінчуватиметься на **голосний**, то пишемо "**Впорядник**", якщо ж на **приголосний** - "**Упорядник**"